# show dataLabels or tooltip on Highcharts packed bubble outer circle

Tags: highcharts

How can I show dataLabels or tooltip for outer circle of `packedbubble`?

For example in [Carbon emissions around the world (2014)](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/packed-bubble-split) sample, i need to show a tooltip for each continent, when hovering on them. or if possible show dataLabels for each of them

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the outer circle is just a path without any properties like x, y etc, so it wouldn't work with the Highcharts tooltip feature. The only solution which came to my mind is to create a custom tooltip on **mouseover** event on this path.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9gkdfsnj/

Code:

```
events: {
      render() {

        var
          chart = this,
          series = chart.series[0],
          graphic = series.parentNode.graphic,
          tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip'),
          text;

        text = "Sum value: " + Math.floor(series.yData.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));

        graphic.element.onmouseover = function() {
          tooltip.style.visibility = "visible";
          tooltip.innerHTML = text;
          tooltip.style.left = graphic.x + (tooltip.offsetWidth /2) - chart.plotLeft + 'px';
          tooltip.style.top = graphic.y + graphic.height / 2 + 'px'
        }

        graphic.element.onmouseout = function() {
          tooltip.style.visibility = "hidden"
        }
      }
    }
```

It is just a simple example, feel free to improve it.

Comment: good point to start, need some tweaks, for example, when hovering on tooltip itself, it is disappeared. but thanks for the idea. also thanks for the sum values :-), i'm going to show percent there

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `value` key

```
[{
   name: 'Animals',
   value: 867,
   data: [{
           name: 'Lion',
           value: 167
          }, {
           name: 'Croatia',
           value: 200
          },
          {
            name: "Dog",
             value: 97
        }],
}]
```

2. Add below lines inside `Tooltip`

```
tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter : function(){
         let childtooltip = "";         
         if(this.point != undefined && this.point != null){
             if((this.point.name != undefined && this.point.name != null) && (this.point.value != undefined && this.point.value != null)){
                 childtooltip = `<b>${this.point.name}:</b> ${this.point.value}`;
             }
         }
         if(childtooltip == ""){
             return `<b>${this.series.userOptions.name}:</b> ${this.series.userOptions.value}<br>`
         }else{
             return `${childtooltip}`;
         }
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/CNpreethi/4kxqusrp/3/)